# App service app gives 404 in incognito mode or clear history

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app in the azure app service which has "index.html" setup as a default document in portal and also url rewrites in web-config (see below). If I go to the site with cleared history or chrome incognito mode it gives me a 404. I can hit the url directly on "mysite.com/index.html" and after that "mysite.com" will work too, but brand new browser session always 404.

I also have below in www_root in attempt to force "index.html" to load but no luck, any ideas?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- IIS URL Rewrite for react routes -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing '/' in url=/index.html and add appendQueryString="true"

Comment: Still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

The default document is the web page that's displayed at the root URL for a website. The first matching file in the list is used. To add a new default document, click New document.

So, you could remove the above and then try adding> In the Azure portal, search for and select App Services, and then select your app. In the app's left menu, select Configuration > Default documents.

If the app uses modules that route based on URL instead of serving static content, there is no need for default documents.

To isolate, try to configure web.config similar to this:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SPA">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Or If you wish to actually rewrite but not redirects, try enabling ARR with applicationHost.xdt file with in the site root folder. If you connect to your site using Kudu console, you will see the deployed files under your site\wwwroot folder - Kudu console (https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net) > From the Kudu Console> Debug Console >> (CMD/PowerShell> Site > wwwroot. >> Shows-up all your deployment files.